# Braking with less resistance

Tags: power, resistors, dc-motor, braking

I have a 500w dc motor that I want to brake with a power resistor. Using ohm's law I can calculate the resistance needed like so

```
R = V^2 / P = 36^2 / 500 = ~2.5 Ohm
```

Building it in real life I'm going to use resistors in parallel rated for 100W, where I'm aware that I probably need less than that but just to be on the safe side I'll use 5 of.

I was wondering though, what would happen if I used less resistance, say 5 x 0.01 Ohm in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
R = V^2 / P = 36^2 / 500 = ~2.5 Ohm
```

It looks like you've assumed it's a 36v motor. It will generate about that when spun at its rated speed, so neglecting losses, this calculation is correct.

If you use very much less than this resistance, then two things will happen.

1) At its rated speed, at 36v output, much more current will flow than you expected, so the braking torque will be higher than you'd planned, as will the braking power.

2) The motor windings and the braking resistor carry the same current. If the braking resistor is very small, then the braking power will be dissipated as heat in the motor. If you just have a spinning motor by itself and stop it, that's not too much heat. If you are stopping a laden vehicle running down a hill, then that will probably overheat your motor. That's why you'll often see the loco for a mountain railway has a rack of air-cooled resistors on the roof, that's where the braking power gets dissipated, not in the motor windings.

Braking with a resistor is dynamic, that is, the braking torque drops as the speed drops. If you want steady braking torque, you need a controllable load. As the motor has an inherent inductance, and as there's no need for clean supplies, this can be done as simply as using a FET and a freewheel diode to chop down to a resistive load, a crude buck converter. Control the switching to control the braking torque as required.

Comment: Oh so when resistance is lower it will allow more current than what the motor is rated for thus the resistors will burn up more power than what is rated and if they are enough in series they will not get damaged but since motor windings' cross section is probably not going to be sufficient to carry this current it will get damaged. I have a side question though, when used as a generator with appropriate resistance so that current does not exceed rated values, is heat still generated in the motor windings?

Comment: What damages a motor is heat. The motor windings can carry even short-circuited current for a while, until they get too hot. Heat is always generated in motor and generator windings (except superconductive ones), as they have resistance. Generally a motor or generator, at rated speed, will have enough cooling so that rated current through the windings doesn't overheat them. Torque motors that are designed to carry rated current down to a standstill will often have a separately driven cooling fan.